# nullpointer exception while accessing childviews of a fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, fragment

I am creating an activity that contains three fragments for tabs.I want to set the data from an object(which is available in parent activity) to the child views of the fragment.I tried doing this through public methods of fragment.But when trying to access the views,It returns null pointer exception and the app crashes.Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Parent activity is :

```
public class EnquiryViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IFragmentToActivity {

    private Context mContext;
    // Session Manager Class
    SessionManagement session;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private Gson gson;

    //String enquiryId;
    int enId, uid;
    Enquiry enquiry;

    // Alert Dialog Manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    /* Button btn_MoreEnqDetails, btn_ToSiteVisit, btn_nextEnq2;
     EditText etName, etAddress, etSiteAddress, etPhoneNo, etMob, etEmail;

     private RadioGroup rgrp_familyType;
     private RadioButton radioSelectedFamilyType;
 */
    private TabLayout addenqtabLayout;
    private ViewPager addenqviewPager;

    //Fragments
    ContactFragment contactFragment;
    RequirementsFragment requirementsFragment;
    FollowUpFragment followupFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_enquiry);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //--------------------------------------------

        //Initializing viewPager
        addenqviewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.addenqviewpager);
        addenqviewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

        //Initializing the tablayout
        addenqtabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.addenqtablayout);
        addenqtabLayout.setupWithViewPager(addenqviewPager);

        addenqviewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                addenqviewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
        });

        setupViewPager(addenqviewPager);

        //----------------------------------------------

        enquiry = new Enquiry();
        try {

            mContext = this;
            enId = getIntent().getIntExtra("EnquiryId", -1);
            uid = getIntent().getIntExtra("UserId", -1);
            if (enId != -1) {
                Log.d("h", "get enqid is " + enId);
                enquiry = EnquiryORM.findEnquiryById(mContext, enId);
            } else {
                Log.d("h", "didn't get bid");
            }

            /*int position = tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition();
            Fragment fragment = adapter.getFragment(tabLayout
                    .getSelectedTabPosition());
            if (fragment != null) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        ((TabFragment1) fragment).onRefresh();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        ((TabFragment2) fragment).onRefresh();
                        break;
                }
            }*/
            contactFragment.setDataToScreen(enquiry);
            contactFragment.disableAllViews();

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            Log.d("NumberFormatException: ", "some int is null");
            Log.d("NumberFormatException: ", e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void communicateToFragment2() {
        /*RequirementsFragment fragment = (RequirementsFragment) adapter.getFragment(1);
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragment.fragmentCommunication();
        } else {
            Log.i("log", "Fragment 2 is not initialized");
        }*/
    }


    @Override
    public void gotoMoreDetails() {

        if (ConnectivityReceiver.isConnected()) {
            //fetch and
            //send indent to next activity to view more details
            //show option to edit details
            fetchMoreEnquiryDetails();

        } else {
            alert.showAlertDialog(EnquiryViewActivity.this, "Network Error", "Internet is not available!\nCannot connect to server", false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void gotoSiteVisit() {

        Intent in = new Intent(EnquiryViewActivity.this, SiteVisitViewActivity.class);
        in.putExtra("EnquiryId", enId);
        in.putExtra("UserId", uid);
        startActivity(in);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveDataContacts(Enquiry enq) {

        if (enquiry != null) {
            enq.setId(enquiry.getId());
            enq.setStatus(enquiry.getStatus());
            enq.setUser_id(enquiry.getUser_id());
            enq.setEnqstatusnew(enquiry.getEnqstatusnew());
            enq.setCreateddate(getDateTime());
        }

        int enI=(int)EnquiryORM.insertEnquiry(mContext, enq);
        enq.setId(enI);
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        contactFragment = new ContactFragment();
        requirementsFragment = new RequirementsFragment();
        followupFragment = new FollowUpFragment();
        adapter.addFragment(contactFragment, "CONTACT DETAILS");
        adapter.addFragment(requirementsFragment, "REQUIREMENTS");
        adapter.addFragment(followupFragment, "FOLLOW-UP");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void fetchMoreEnquiryDetails() {
        // Get a RequestQueue
        // RequestQueue requestQueue = MyVolleySingleton.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //create gson instance which is used to parse json
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();
        //gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("M/d/yy hh:mm a");
        gson = gsonBuilder.create();

        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, EndPoints.GET_SELECTED_ENQUIRIES_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                Log.d("d", "getting response.........\n" + response);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected Enquiry JSON data :" + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //Enquiry detailEnquiry = gson.fromJson(response, Enquiry.class);
                //detailEnquiry.setUser_id(uid);
                Enquiry detailEnquiry = new Enquiry();

                List<Enquiry> enquiryList = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(response, Enquiry[].class));
                for (Enquiry enqu : enquiryList) {
                    detailEnquiry = enqu;
                }
                forwardToViewEnquiryMoreDetails(detailEnquiry);

                /*Log.d("e", "All data inserted...now display.........");
                List<Enquiry> enqlist= EnquiryORM.getEnquiries(getBaseContext());
                for(Enquiry i:enqlist) {
                    Log.d("e", "enquiry :" +i.getId());
                    Log.d("e", i.getName()+","+i.getStatus()+","+i.getAddress()+","+i.getUser_id());
                }
*/
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Log.e("EnqViewActivity", error.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Log.d("d", "inside getparams()...\n");
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("enquiryid", String.valueOf(enId));
                params.put("userid", String.valueOf(uid));
                Log.d("d", "enquiry id to pass:" + enId + "\n");
                return params;
            }
        };

        // Add the request to RequestQueue.
        // MyVolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(sr);
        requestQueue.add(sr);
        Log.d("d", "Added to queue");
    }

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

    private void forwardToViewEnquiryMoreDetails(Enquiry detailedEnquiry) {

        Gson mynewgson = new Gson();
        String DEnquiryDataObjectAsString = mynewgson.toJson(detailedEnquiry);

        Intent toDetail = new Intent(EnquiryViewActivity.this, EnquiryViewMoreActivity.class);
        toDetail.putExtra("DetailedEnquiryDataObjectAsString", DEnquiryDataObjectAsString);
        startActivity(toDetail);
        // close this activity
        //finish();
    }

    private String getDateTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);

    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.view_enq, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_add_enquiry) {
            startActivity(new Intent(EnquiryViewActivity.this, EnquiryAddActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_edit_enquiry) {
            // Make all fields editable
            contactFragment.enableAllViews();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Fragment code is :

```
public class ContactFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private IFragmentToActivity mCallback;

    Button btn_MoreEnqDetails, btn_ToSiteVisit, btn_nextEnq1;
    EditText etName, etAddress, etSiteAddress, etPhoneNo, etMob, etEmail;

    public ContactFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact, container, false);

        btn_MoreEnqDetails = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_MoreEnqDetails);
        btn_ToSiteVisit = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_ToSiteVisit);
        btn_nextEnq1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_nextEnq1);

        etName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etClientName);
        etAddress = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etAddress);
        etSiteAddress = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etSiteAddress);
        etPhoneNo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etPhoneNo);
        etMob = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etMob);
        etEmail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etEmail);

        btn_MoreEnqDetails.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_ToSiteVisit.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_nextEnq1.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_MoreEnqDetails:
                mCallback.showToast("Hello from Fragment 1");
                break;

            case R.id.btn_ToSiteVisit:
                mCallback.gotoSiteVisit();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_nextEnq1:
                Enquiry enq=new Enquiry();
                enq=getDataFromViews(enq);
                mCallback.saveDataContacts(enq);
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            mCallback = (IFragmentToActivity) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement IFragmentToActivity");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        mCallback = null;
        super.onDetach();
    }

    public void onRefresh() {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fragment 1: Refresh called.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    public void disableAllViews() {

        Log.d("EnqViewAct: ", "disabling all views..");
        btn_MoreEnqDetails.setEnabled(false);
        btn_ToSiteVisit.setEnabled(false);
        btn_nextEnq1.setEnabled(false);
        etName.setEnabled(false);
        etAddress.setEnabled(false);
        etSiteAddress.setEnabled(false);
        etPhoneNo.setEnabled(false);
        etMob.setEnabled(false);
        etEmail.setEnabled(false);

    }

    public void enableAllViews() {

        Log.d("EnqViewAct: ", "enabling all views..");
        btn_MoreEnqDetails.setEnabled(true);
        btn_ToSiteVisit.setEnabled(true);
        btn_nextEnq1.setEnabled(true);
        etName.setEnabled(true);
        etAddress.setEnabled(true);
        etSiteAddress.setEnabled(true);
        etPhoneNo.setEnabled(true);
        etMob.setEnabled(true);
        etEmail.setEnabled(true);

    }

    public void setDataToScreen(Enquiry enquiry) {

        Log.d("EbqViewAct","Data to display : "
                +enquiry.getId()+","+enquiry.getUser_id()+","+
                enquiry.getStatus()+","+enquiry.getEnqstatusnew()+","+
                enquiry.getCreateddate()+","+
                enquiry.getName()+","+enquiry.getAddress()+","+
                enquiry.getSiteaddress()+","+enquiry.getPhone_number()+","+
                enquiry.getMobile_number()+","+enquiry.getEmail());

        if(enquiry.getName()!=null && enquiry.getName()!="")
        {etName.setText(enquiry.getName());}
        if(enquiry.getAddress()!=null && enquiry.getAddress()!="")
        {etAddress.setText(enquiry.getAddress());}
        if(enquiry.getSiteaddress()!=null && enquiry.getSiteaddress()!="")
        {etSiteAddress.setText(enquiry.getSiteaddress());}
        if(enquiry.getPhone_number()!=null && enquiry.getPhone_number()!="")
        {etPhoneNo.setText(enquiry.getPhone_number());}
        if(enquiry.getMobile_number()!=null && enquiry.getMobile_number()!="")
        {etMob.setText(enquiry.getMobile_number());}
        if(enquiry.getEmail()!=null && enquiry.getEmail()!="")
        {etEmail.setText(enquiry.getEmail());}

       /* if (thisSv.getFamilytype() != null) {
            if (thisSv.getFamilytype().equalsIgnoreCase("Nuclear")) {
                rgrp_familyType.check(R.id.rbtn_nuclear);
            } else if (thisSv.getFamilytype().equalsIgnoreCase("Join")) {
                rgrp_familyType.check(R.id.rbtn_join);
            } else {
                rgrp_familyType.check(R.id.rbtn_nuclear);
            }
        }*/

    }

    public Enquiry getDataFromViews(Enquiry enq) {

      /*
        radioSelectedFamilyType = (RadioButton) findViewById(rgrp_familyType.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        if (radioSelectedFamilyType != null) {
            newSv.setFamilytype(radioSelectedFamilyType.getText().toString());
        }*/

        if ((etName.getText().toString()) != "" && (etName.getText().toString()) != null) {
            enq.setName(etName.getText().toString().trim());
        }
        if ((etAddress.getText().toString()) != "" && (etAddress.getText().toString()) != null) {
            enq.setAddress(etAddress.getText().toString().trim());
        }
        if ((etSiteAddress.getText().toString()) != "" && (etSiteAddress.getText().toString()) != null) {
            enq.setSiteaddress(etSiteAddress.getText().toString().trim());
        }
        if ((etPhoneNo.getText().toString()) != "" && (etPhoneNo.getText().toString()) != null) {
            enq.setPhone_number(etPhoneNo.getText().toString().trim());
        }
        if ((etMob.getText().toString()) != "" && (etMob.getText().toString()) != null) {
            enq.setMobile_number(etMob.getText().toString().trim());
        }
        if ((etEmail.getText().toString()) != "" && (etEmail.getText().toString()) != null) {
            enq.setEmail(etEmail.getText().toString().trim());
        }
        return enq;
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    }

}
```

Interface is :

```
public interface IFragmentToActivity {

    void showToast(String msg);
    void communicateToFragment2();

    void gotoMoreDetails();
    void gotoSiteVisit();
    void saveDataContacts(Enquiry enq);

}
```

PagerAdapter is :

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final SparseArray<WeakReference<Fragment>> instantiatedFragments = new SparseArray<>();
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object){
        return super.getItemPosition(object);

    }
//--------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        final Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        instantiatedFragments.put(position, new WeakReference<>(fragment));
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position, final Object object) {
        instantiatedFragments.remove(position);
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    @Nullable
    public Fragment getFragment(final int position) {
        final WeakReference<Fragment> wr = instantiatedFragments.get(position);
        if (wr != null) {
            return wr.get();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Error log is :

```
12-25 11:09:46.931 3136-3136/com.example.anjana.decorightkitchen E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.example.anjana.decorightkitchen, PID: 3136
                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.anjana.decorightkitchen/com.example.anjana.decorightkitchen.activity.EnquiryViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                       at com.example.anjana.decorightkitchen.fragment.ContactFragment.setDataToScreen(ContactFragment.java:149)
                                                                                       at com.example.anjana.decorightkitchen.activity.EnquiryViewActivity.onCreate(EnquiryViewActivity.java:140)
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

NOTE : Enquiry object values are getting in the fragment properly.
   enqName.setText("hai") is working properly inside onCreateView() of fragment.
But when enqName.setText("hai") put inside a public method of fragment,and called that method from onCreateView(), again nullpointer exception occurs.

Comment: post your error log also

Comment: edited to add error log @Tej

Comment: have you received your data `enquiry.getName()`  ? in your contact fragment ?

Comment: yes...i'm getting the enquiry object data in Contact fragment  @Tej

Comment: then there might be your edittext initialization problem . so please ensure your `findViewbyId` of all edittext with their respected Id

Comment: I tried commenting all the lines containing reference to editText  'name'.Then the same error occurs for next edit text 'address'.

Comment: do not comment . i'm telling you to check your edittext initialization . see my above comment

Comment: there is no problem with the ids.The ids in xml and those in findViewbyId  are exactly same.

Comment: check if current fragment is instance of YourFragment then set text to it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: How should i do that? Could you please explain it?  @Atif AbbAsi

Answer (score 0):

from your code and your error log

```
void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

seems like , there might be chances of only two problems .

1. Your Edittext initialization problem  , May be With your `finViewByID` or your 
   id name `(R.id.checkthis)`
2. As you are enabling and disabling your views . So Be sure when you 
   **setText** , your view is `Enable` and Not `Visibility.Gone`.

As you already checked your `enquiry` object . its working well . so I think these might be causing  `NullPointerException`

Comment: removing enabllng and disabling methods didn't worked!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this.?

```
  Fragment home = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
                    if (home instanceof HomeFragment) {
                        ((HomeFragment)home).setData(data);
                    }
```

Answer (score -1):

To send data to a fragment at the time of the creation you can set Arguments for the fragment when you creating it and than you can retrieve it later like this :

```
public static ContactFragment newInstance(String data, int data2) {
        ContactFragment  fragment = new ContactFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("someData", data);
        bundle.putInt("otherData", data2);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }
```

When you call your fragment use this constructor like this :

```
ContactFragment fragment = ContactFragment.newInstance("firstData",1200);
```

In your fragment you can retrieve the data anywhere like this :

```
int variable = getArguments().getInt("otherData");
String string = getArguments().getString("someData");
```

Hope this will help.